# Raise float into the power - print formula

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to print the following:

```
"$y = 0.25x^1.99$"
```

But the result is as follows:

[image: i]

But I need the **1.99** to be in power all together, of course.
I searched a lot but cannot find the solution as I may getting the terminolgy wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Not clear how this is a python question. Did you try parenthesis?

Comment: No I didn't try the parenthesis (that is what I was looking for), thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm not sure why it is related to python but what you're looking for is : `"$y = 0.25x^{1.99}$"`

I tested it with matplotlib since you don't mention what you're trying to do with it, and it works as intended.

Comment: It was the { } I was looking. Thanks.